# How do I prevent my UITableViewCell's contents from overlapping other cells when using insert animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview, uidatepicker

**Sample project:** http://d.pr/f/Tkld

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that very simply has a single `UIDatePicker` view as its only subview.

Like Calendar.app I want to show an inline date picker when the user taps on a cell. My code for doing this works well (I simply have Auto Layout calculate the height and it grows perfectly), however the date picker overlaps the other content as the cell grows, which looks very weird.

In the following screenshot you can see "One More Cell" animating into place right in the middle of the date picker.

[image]

How do I prevent this behaviour? The cell, the cell's contentView, and the date picker itself all have `clipsToBounds` on, so I don't know how it's even doing this or what I should be doing.

I attached a sample project above showing it in the smallest possible scenario. It's easiest to see in the Simulator with "Slow Animations" on (Debug > Slow Animations), where you'll see the date picker cell draw outside of its bounds throughout the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`, and making the cell height larger for the date picker cell.  I didn't see it in the sample project.  This will make sure your cells have the proper height when displayed.

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` isn't necessary for Auto Layout cells, it effectively returns `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and calculates itself based on the cell's constraints. For what it's worth I've tried using only frame calculations instead of Auto Layout and the result is the same.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't used that before.  I ran the project and...it works as you expected (iPhone 6, 9.3)!  Which version/simulator did you use?

Comment: Turn on Slow Animations (Debug > Slow Animations or command-T) and you'll be able to see it. I've tried iPhone 6s simulator iOS 9.3, also on device.

Comment: I understand now.  I thought you meant that the cells' final position ended up being stuck on top of each other. Will have to think more on this one then.

Comment: Ah, no, sorry for the lack of clarity, I meant more so that the date picker cell draws out of its bounds (doesn't respect `clipToBounds`) throughout the animation.